# Autolayout with equal width and setting priority

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

Hi I need to display 3 or 4 buttons based on some condition for that I am using following constraints (image below). 
[image]

It works fine when I have 4 view, but for 3 buttons, first button is not sized equally, but rest of the buttons are aligned with equal width (image below). I have set priority 990 for horizontal spacing constraint,  so rest works fine. [image]

I am setting all the autolayout constraints in storyboard.

How can I achieve equal width when I remove middle view?

Comment: set constraint of each button with every button in the view

Comment: You need to remove the constraints then add the constraints back to the 3 buttons after you remove the view. When you add the 4th button back, you need to add the constraints back to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS9 only apps:

This might be a good time to use the new `Horizontal Stack View`. Just set `distribution` to `fill equally` and `alignment` to `fill`

For iOS8 support:

You'll have to set the width constraint to `equal width` between the components and the `horizontal spacing` to 0

Set button1 to equal width with button2 then button1 to equal width with button3. This should be enough.

Comment: Horizontal Stack View is available from iOS 9+, I need to support from iOS8+

Comment: yes. It's a shame. Otherwise it's a pretty useful component.

Comment: Thats done, thats the reason 3rd and 4th buttons have same width.

Comment: Just tried it with three buttons and it works just fine. Sett b1.w = b2.w and b1.w = b3.w as I wrote above.

Answer (score 0):

Create 3 buttons, and set their width and height equal to parent(Superview).
Next set the multiplier property on **"width constraint"** for each button **with "1/3" value** like that:

[image]

[image]

Comment: For some condition I need to display 3 buttons and for few conditions I need to display 4 buttons. So in storyboard I'll be having 4 buttons and in the code based on condition I am removing the second button. Ideally it's a 4 button view.

Comment: Okay, so maybe the easier way is to set your constraint programmatically ?